# Xperia Sola- Whatsapp Web not being able to scan the Bar Code

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, whatsapp-messenger, barcode

I have successfully managed to chat on whatsapp web two times, but since yesterday it just won't read the bar code. I have tried it horizontally and vertically, placed it for minutes and also tried moving the phone throughout the code so that it reads at least somewhere, but it just would not work. Advise.

Comment: Also, my camera opens only in 1/4th of the screen space, rest is a black-shade area covering the camera screen. Although the camera is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your internet is working smoothly. As after scan it need to send data to server and then it get connected to web. I think your device is scanning clearly bt reason its failing is due to poor internet.. Let me know you succeed connecting??

Answer (score 0):

I've got the problem solved today, while I was PRT SCRning the problem.

All you have to do is move your phone more Left, because of that black half screen bug it scans blank space near QR code.

Answer (score 0):

when you are at whatsapp web screen on your phone that view on 1/4 of screen is wrong get a screenshot you will see where you really are and then center qr code due to screen shoots its a lot easier :D